# Update pandas dataframe and add new columns

Tags: python, pandas

**Question:**

How can I update a pandas dataframe by the rows of another dataframe, while adding new columns if the other dataframe has columns not appearing in the original dataframe?

**Example:**

I have two dataframes:

```
original_df = pd.DataFrame([{'name' : 'ruben','age' : 25},{'name' : 'henk', 'age' : 26},{'name' : 'gijs', 'age' : 20}],index=[0,1,2])

    name  age
0   ruben  25
1   henk   26
2   gijs   20
```

and

```
update_df = pd.DataFrame([{'name' : 'henk','age' : 27,'hobby' : 'football'},{'name' : 'gijs', 'age' : 21,'hobby' : 'music'}],index=[1,2])

   name  age     hobby
1  henk   27  football
2  gijs   21     music
```

I want to update original_df with the rows of update_df. If they all would contain the same rows, i could do this as following:

```
original_df.update(update_df)
```

However, this results in:

```
    name  age
0  ruben  25
1   henk  27
2   gijs  21
```

How can i make sure the new column is added as well, so to get this result:

```
    name  age hobby
0  ruben  25
1   henk  27  football
2   gijs  21  music
```

Thank you in advance

**Edit for Answer:** This question was marked as a duplicate (by linking a general question about merging 101), but don't follow the link. The correct answer is in the comments:

```
update_df.combine_first(original_df)
```

Comment: `update_df.combine_first(original_df)`?

Comment: @HenryYik This seems to work, thank you. Feel free to add it as an answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left-join: "Left join, also known as Left Outer Join, returns a dataframe containing all the rows of the left dataframe" ([Source](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/02/joins-in-pandas-master-the-different-types-of-joins-in-python/#:%7E:text=Left%20Join%20in%20Pandas,-Now%2C%20let%27s%20say&text=Left%20join%2C%20also%20known%20as,columns%20in%20the%20right%20dataframe.)). There is also a good thread about it on Stack Overflow: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

```
original_df = pd.DataFrame([{'name' : 'ruben','age' : 25},{'name' : 'henk', 'age' : 26},{'name' : 'gijs', 'age' : 20}],index=[0,1,2])
update_df = pd.DataFrame([{'name' : 'henk','age' : 27,'hobby' : 'football'},{'name' : 'gijs', 'age' : 21,'hobby' : 'music'}],index=[1,2])

df_merged = original_df.merge(update_df, on = 'name', how = 'left')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this creates two columns: age_x and age_y instead of one updated column.